# In the sentence “Have you deleted your account?”, what is the tense and grammar rules involved?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, questions, conjugations

In the sentence “Have you deleted your account?”, what is the tense and grammar rules involved?

I was trying to ask a friend this and realized I don't know what is going on with the grammar here. If anyone could provide a good free resource to learn grammar rules of all tenses it would be awesome.

Comment: For a resource, have a look at the meta post https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english

Comment: For the rest of the question, I'm not quite sure what kind of answer you want. Since your apparent level is good (you use complex grammar like "I was trying to ask" but the question is very basic: It's a present perfect question. Normally that is taught at school, and you seem to be beyond that.  Perhaps you could explain what you think the tense should be and why you are uncertain?

Comment: As you noticed, my english is advanced but all I’ve learned was practical, nerver had formal education, so I know the “how” but not the “why”. English is not my native language. What I want to know is where I can learn those “why”s of grammar and for free. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have deleted my account

is in the present perfect tense and indicative mode. That tense has several uses, one being to express an action that occurred in the recent past but is not occurring now.

Questions, the interrogative mode, are formed by shifting an auxiliary verb before the subject.

> Have you deleted your account?

That is also in the present perfect tense, but in the interrogative mode. It is asking whether or not the account is deleted. It implies that the deletion, if it occurred, must have been recent. Otherwise, it likely would have been asked

> Did you delete your account?